# How to pass data into CollectionType form and get it there?

Tags: symfony4, symfony-forms

How can I get in correct way data which send into a collection?

Important:

> If I delete from the Create Form class this line:
>
> ```
> 'data'=> array_values($builder->getData()->cpus), //TODO: shit code send data And add in Collection
> ```
>
> And add in Collection Form class this:
>
> ```
> 'data_class' => Command::class, //namespace (Collection\Command)
> ```
>
> This works only in view (twig) stage, but firstly I have to get those
>   data before creating collection form (view).

How can I do that?

At this moment I found this solution (which looks "shitty") :). Lines marked as **TODO**

Collection\Command:

```
class Command
{
    public $id_item;
    /**
     * @var ItemInterface $interface
     */
    public $interface;
    public $id_object;

    public function __construct(string $id_item, ItemInterface $interface)
    {
        $this->id_item = $id_item;
        $this->interface = $interface;
    }

    public function getIdItem(): string
    {
        return $this->id_item;
    }

    public function getInterface(): ItemInterface
    {
        return $this->interface;
    }
}
```

**There is the problem, I can't get data from $cpus in good way** :)

Collection\Form:

```
class Form extends AbstractType
{
    private $cpuModelFetcher;

    public function __construct(CpuModelFetcher $cpuModelFetcher)
    {
        $this->cpuModelFetcher = $cpuModelFetcher;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $index = (int)$builder->getName(); //TODO: shit code - use name of form as index.
        /**
         * @var Command $command
         */
        $command = $builder->getData()[$index]; //TODO: shit code get data from array

        $builder
            ->add('id_object', Type\ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'choices' => array_flip($this->cpuModelFetcher->getSupportedCpuModelListForModelBasedDeviceBySocketType(
                        $command->getIdItem(),$command->getInterface()->getId())),
                    'placeholder' => 'not installed in '.$command->getInterface()->getName().' socket.',
                    'required' => false,
                ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //'data_class' => Command::class,
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

Create Command:

```
class Command
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $id;
    public $cpus;

    private function __construct(Id $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public static function fromDevice(Device $device): self
    {
        $command = new self($device->getId());
        if($device->getBasedType()->isModelBasedDevice()){
            $command->cpus = $command->transformDeviceModelInterfaceCollectionToCommandArray($device->getId(),
                $device->getModelBasedDevice()->getDeviceModel()->getCpuInterfaces());
        }

        return $command;
    }

    private function transformDeviceModelInterfaceCollectionToCommandArray(Id $id_item, ArrayCollection $interfaces): array
    {
        $object_specific_interfaces = [];
        foreach ($interfaces as $one){
            /**
             * @var DeviceModelInterface $one
             */
            for($i=0; $i<$one->getAmount(); $i++){
                $object_specific_interfaces[] = new Collection\Command($id_item->getValue(), $one->getInterface());
            }
        }
        unset($one);
        return $object_specific_interfaces;
    }
}
```

Create Form:

```
class Form extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        //dump($builder);
        $builder
            ->add('cpus', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'entry_type' => Collection\Form::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'data'=> array_values($builder->getData()->cpus), //TODO: shit code send data
                ],
                'by_reference' => true,
                'allow_add' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true,
            ])
            ->add('save', Type\SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Command::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution which looks more better, I just get data from PRE_SET_DATA event in the class Collection\Form.

```php
class Form extends AbstractType
    {
        private $cpuModelFetcher;
    
        public function __construct(CpuModelFetcher $cpuModelFetcher)
        {
            $this->cpuModelFetcher = $cpuModelFetcher;
        }
    
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
        {
    
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        }
    
        protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, $data): void
        {
            /**
             * @var Command $data
             */
            $form->add('id_object', Type\ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'choices' => array_flip($this->cpuModelFetcher->getSupportedCpuModelListForModelBasedDeviceBySocketType(
                        $data->getIdItem(), $data->getInterface()->getId())),
                    'placeholder' => 'not installed in '.$data->getInterface()->getName().' socket.',
                    'required' => false,
                ]);
            //dump($data);
            //dump($form);
        }
    
        function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event): void
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
    
            $this->addElements($form, $data);
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Command::class,
            ));
        }
    }
```

In any case, if someone knows another solution, I will be glad to hear it.

Thanks.